# What does this error message mean? ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle

I am writing my SQL statements in Oracle Application Express and keep getting the error message ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis. Below is the code that I have written to create a table.

```
CREATE TABLE book
  (
     book_isbn   CHAR(13),
     book_name   VARCHAR(20),
     book_author VARCHAR(20),
     book_pages  CHAR(4),
     book_price  NUM(4, 2),
     PRIMARY KEY(book_isbn)
  );
```

Comment: `NUMBER` instead of `NUM`.

Comment: Putting NUMBER fixed the problem! Thank you!

Comment: Also it's `varchar2`, not `varchar` (or `char`, which is technically valid but best avoided).

Answer (score 0):

Please change Num to Number:

```
CREATE TABLE DSSB_DE.book
  (
     book_isbn   CHAR(13),
     book_name   VARCHAR(20),
     book_author VARCHAR(20),
     book_pages  CHAR(4),
     book_price  NUMBER(4, 2),
     PRIMARY KEY(book_isbn)
  );
```